# About one of the ways to handle a failure of a malloc()

Tags: c, error-handling, malloc

I've known some ways for handling a failure of a malloc() and I prefer the way to use a result of a malloc() like some example code below. But actually I don't know well how this phrase is actually work. Can anybody give me some advice about using this phrase ?

"if ((result = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1))) != 0)"

```
char    strjoin(char const *s1, char const *s2)
{
    char    *result;
    int     idx;

    if ((result = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1))) != 0)
    {
        idx = 0;
        while (*s1)
            result[idx++] = *s1++;
        while (*s2)
            result[idx++] = *s2++;
        result[idx] = 0;
        return (result);
    }
    return (0); 
}
```

Found some example codes i.e. using same phrase

Comment: Note that the `return result;` can just be relocated out of the `if` body, replacing `return 0;` afterward, which may also give some insight as to what that conditional is actually doing (albeit poorly).

Comment: `return result;` should result in some compiler warning. You are returning a pointer instead of a single `char`.

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are asking. Are you asking what that specific line is doing or are you asking whether it's good coding style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char strjoin...` is a bug which prevents this code from compiling. It should obviously be `char*`.

`malloc` returns a pointer if successful, otherwise a null pointer. `result` gets assigned either of these and evaluate to not zero or zero accordingly.

Please note that assignment inside an `if` condition is regarded as poor and dangerous practice, so it should be avoided.

`sizeof(char) * ...` is nonsense. The very definition of `sizeof` is that `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1. Multiplying something with a constant guaranteed to be 1 is just useless bloat.

`strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1` sums up the length of two strings and then + 1 to make room for the null terminator.

Note that lines like `result[idx++] = *s1++;` have no less than 3 side effects in a single line, which is very bad practice. It is recommended to only have 1 side effect in an expression, to prevent sequencing/order of evaluation bugs.

Copying characters 1 by 1 is naive, `memcpy` is likely much faster than that.

There is no need for `idx` since we already know the length of each string from previous `strlen` calls. The programmer should have saved it down at that point. Instead they are making the program needlessly slow.

Consider a complete rewrite of this questionable code into something more readable and efficient:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* strjoin (const char *s1, const char* s2)
{
    size_t length1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t length2 = strlen(s2);

    char* result = malloc(length1 + length2 + 1);
    if(result == NULL)
      return NULL;

    memcpy(result, s1, length1);
    memcpy(result+length1, s2, length2);
    result[length1+length2] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot. It really is helped me out to understand.